# transcoding movie files between android and ios devices

Tags: android, ios, video-processing, transcoding, mov

I have an iOS and Android app that allows users to capture videos and post on our server, then allows them to email the videos to other members.

Problem is videos taken from iOS devices do not play on Android devices, I think the reverse is not a problem.

Does anyone know any server side video transcoding tools that are pretty easy to set up so that i can convert all videos into a common format that will play on any device?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

You can use it in your back-end system. This task should be asynchronous as it can be time consuming. Also you need to limit the size of the media about to be transcoded, and their number, as this kind of tasks can rapidly cause important performance issues.

On the other hand, the Android user may play the media shared by an iOS user with many of the  free FFMPEG enabled players on the Play Store such as [MXPLayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=fr). So using or building a whole server side transcoding system might be an important overhead.